# Clarifying a step in calculating a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Here is the question:

[Correcting the calculation of a norm and continuity of a sequence of functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538839/correcting-the-calculation-of-a-norm-and-continuity-of-a-sequence-of-functions/3538945?noredirect=1#comment7279807_3538945)

in the solution given by infinity  I do not understand this step in the line before last the last part.

$|\int_0^1g_n h|\to \int_0^1|h|$$

Could anyone explain this for me please? does this is because $$|\int_0^1g_n h | \leq \int_0^1 \left\lvert g_n h \right\rvert \leq \lVert g_n \rVert_ {\max} \int_0^1 | h| \leq \lVert h \rVert_1 \quad \text{as} \quad \|g_{n}\|_{max} \leq 1~?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g_n\to sgn(h)$ in $L^1$, we may (by picking a subsequence) suppose without loss of generality that $g_n \to sgn(h)$ almost everywhere. Note also that $|g_n h|\leq |h|$. By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]} g_n h
=\int_{[0,1]}\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n h
=\int_{[0,1]}sgn(h) h
=\int_{[0,1]} |h|.
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104310/discussion-on-answer-by-quoka-clarifying-a-step-in-calculating-a-norm).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549737/proving-the-riesz-representation-theorem-for-the-space-of-1-point-with-the-count (if you have time could you look at it please?)